# Displaying my HttpStatusCodeResult error description using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following inside my custom authorization class:-

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "json permission denied");
               }
```

and using jquery i can catch the error code as follow:-

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e,xhr,textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (xhr.status == 401)
            window.location = "/Account/Login";
        else if (xhr.status == 403)
            jAlert(xhr.staus, "You have no enough permissions to request this resource.");
    });
```

but i am not sure how i can catch the error message "json permission denied"

Comment: it should be in `xhr.responseText`

Comment: this will display a full page error description ..

Comment: try on e object then xd, do a json stringify on all those objects and ull insta find it

Comment: xhr.statusText will work , i tried it